# Can't make background image change when hovering over link

Tags: css

I have the following CSS code:

```
.menu a:link {
    background-image: url('img/cookieWhole.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 25px 25px;
    background-position: 15% 50%;
}

.menu a:visited {
    background-image: url('img/cookieBitten.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 25px 25px;
    background-position: 15% 50%;
    color: #2d548b;
}

.menu a:hover {
    background-image: url('img/img/cookieWholeHover.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 25px 25px;
    background-position: 15% 50%;
    background-color: rgb(255, 171, 14);
}
```

When hovering over the links, the background image changes.  But after visiting the links, the background image doesn't change (when I set the visited link color to something else it does change)  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try changing `.menu a:link` to `.menu a`.

Comment: Tried it and still doesn't change.

Comment: a means all kind of links, while :link only refers to unvisited links, so thats exactly what he wanted...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can't change the background-image for visited links.  [Browser restrictions!](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:visited)
Only thing allowed to change are:

1. color
2. background-color
3. border-color (and border-color for separate sides)
4. outline color
5. column-rule-color
6. the color parts of fill and stroke

Answer (score 1):

This is disabled for security reasons...

[**MDN**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:visited)

> For privacy reasons, browsers strictly limit which styles you can apply using this pseudo-class, and how they can be used:

> Allowable CSS properties are `color, background-color, border-color, border-bottom-color, border-left-color, border-right-color, border-top-color, column-rule-color, outline-color, text-decoration-color,` and `text-emphasis-color`.